# Cargo: how does it find git binary to use

Tags: git, rust, rust-cargo

In light of the new security vulnerability in git (quickly patched), I'm wondering how to verify the particular git binary `cargo` uses for cloning repositories to verify that it has the patch?

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=2021

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cargo does not call any `git` binary. It [internally uses the git2 crate](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L35), which binds `libgit2`.

The `libgit2` that `git2` binds to is included as a Git submodule and it currently points to [version 1.0.0](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/v1.0.0).

Comment: Ahh I didn't think to look at the crate dependencies for cargo.